# Saving an *expression* to a shell variable, not the *result* of an expression

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, sh, zsh

**Problem** :

I want to get the latest csv file in the downloads folder by typing `$LATEST`. When I dereference `$LATEST` I want to see the last csv file put in there.

**What I have tried** :

1. `'ls -t $DL/*.csv | head -1'` (this works)
2. `export $LATEST='ls -t $DL/*.csv | head -1'`

The problem with 2. is it always returns the latest file at the time export is run. (e.g. `old.csv`) When I add a new file (e.g. `new.csv`) I want `$LATEST` to show `new.csv` not `old.csv`.

Comment: ["I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables don't track changes in system state. They have values. Those values persist until you change them. If you want variable-like access to the current state, use a function. Example:

```
latest() {
    ls -t $DL/*.csv | head -1
}

echo "The latest file is $(latest)"
if [ "new.csv" = "$(latest)" ]; then
    echo "Hooray, new is latest!"
fi
```

A side benefit is that functions can take arguments. For example, if you wanted to make your `latest` function generic, but with reasonable defaults, you could do:

```
latest() {
    ls -t ${1:-$DL}/*.csv | head -${2:-1}
}
latest # show the 1 latest file from $DL directory
latest /tmp # show the 1 latest file from /tmp
latest /tmp 5 # show the five latest files from /tmp
```

In this case

Answer (score 2):

The environment variable won't get updated automatically, it just stores the value. But you can define a function that will evaluate the expression from 1. every time your call it:

```
function latest {
  ls -t $DL/*.csv | head -1
}
```

Now if you put it in your `~/.bashrc` and reload, you can call `latest` to evaluate the expression and get the result.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use `zsh`, it's much easier:

```
$ latest () { print "$DL"/*.csv(om[1]) }
```

The glob qualifier `om` sorts the expansion of `"$DL"/*.csv` by date; the `[1]` selects on the first element of the sorted expansion.

This avoids any concern about filenames containing newlines, which is the reason why parsing the output of `ls` should be avoided in theory.